# azure-streamanalytics-cicd failing when "SqlReferenceProperties" has "User" field populated

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Trying to set up CI/CD pipeline for Azure Stream analytics following the doc and VS code with SA extension installed with one "Data Stream" input and one "Reference data" input (SQL database).

`azure-streamanalytics-cicd build -project src/asaproj.json`

is working fine when "User" property in ref data config left empty:

[image]

but as soon as I change it to any value build starts failing with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" message:
[image]

("Password" field doesn't seem to make any difference)

So, how can I configure reference data? Leaving it empty is not an option as users will want to run jobs locally.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with exactly the same error.
My pipeline ran without any issues 2 weeks ago. Now, against the same commit, it returns the error above. I think the problem may be with Microsoft.

Comment: I'm looking into it and will keep you posted

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you please let me know which version of the npm package you are using (npm list -g)? Have you updated to the latest version (2.2.3) (npm i azure-streamanalytics-cicd)?

Comment: Just checked - it is 2.2.3.
To reproduce:
 - create new SA project in VS Code.
 - add ref input and set user to any value
 - run build command (azure-streamanalytics-cicd build -project src/asaproj.json)
this way it is failing every time

Comment: Thanks, I was able to reproduce it now. Will open a bug internally and keep you posted. It looks like this happen when using the option "provide settings manually". Have you tried the "select from your Azure Subscriptions" option?

Comment: @AlexSysoiev we are working on a fix. In the meantime can you use version 2.2.2 as a workaround? npm i azure-streamanalytics-cicd@2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release of the package solves the issue: [version 2.2.4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-streamanalytics-cicd)